# "Multiple" searches with Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Basically, I'm trying to get a value from one table and then search for that value in 3 other tables. But I want to do this all in one query.

`select user_id from users where email = 'bob@example.com`

The value from that search needs to go into a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON (table1.user_id = 
table2.user_id)
WHERE table1.user_id  =  <<<THE RESULTS FROM THE FIRST QUERY>>>
OR table2.user_id = <<<THE RESULTS FROM THE FIRST QUERY>>>
```

If the user_id isn't in the first table will this JOIN still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CTE - [Common Table Expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) (which AFAIK is always materialized in Postgres) will serve the purpose as a placeholder for your first query, which you can then use to join into the other tables. Further, a [`UNION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/queries-union.html) sounds like what you want as the `OR` style finding matching data in one or more of the tables `t1 .. t3`, e.g.:

```
WITH cteUsers AS
(
    select user_id from users where email = 'bob@example.com'
)
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.othercol, ...
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN cteUsers cte on t1.user_id = cte.user_id
UNION
SELECT t2.user_id, t2.othercol, ...
FROM table1 t2 INNER JOIN cteUsers cte on t2.user_id = cte.user_id
UNION
SELECT t3.user_id, t3.othercol, ...
FROM table1 t3 INNER JOIN cteUsers cte on t3.user_id = cte.user_id;
```

With the notes:

- The number, and the types returned in the `othercol` columns in the various tables `t1..t3` must match.
- If the same user is matched in multiple tables with the same `othercol` values, then `UNION` will have the effect of removing duplicates (similar to `DISTINCT`). Replace this with `UNION ALL` if you want the duplicate rows.
- If more than one table `t1 .. t3` succeeds in matching the join to `users`, then this will return one row per table matched (unless it is removed by the distinct, as per above)
- If there are no matches in any of tables 1, 2 or 3, then the query will return nothing at all. If you want a single row returned from `users` irrespective of a match (`with nulls for unmatched columns`), then a `LEFT JOIN` between users and at least one of the tables t1..t3 is needed

**Edit - Re: Ensuring that a `users` row always returns at least one record / indicate which table(s) are matched**

As hinted above, you can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to handle the case where there's no matches in any of the 3 tables at all. Here, I've rolled up the output of the 3 table matches into another CTE, and then do one final LOJ between the CTE's, with a `coalesce` to highlight where the join fails (you can obviously also leave this `null`, if required):

```
WITH cteUsers AS
(
    -- Replace with bob to see a match in 2 tables
    -- Replace with fred to see a match in 1 table.
    select user_id from users where email = 'missing@example.com' 
),
cteTables AS
(
  SELECT t1.user_id, 'MatchedTable1' as match, t1.othercol
  FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN cteUsers cte on t1.user_id = cte.user_id
  UNION
  SELECT t2.user_id, 'MatchedTable2' as match, t2.othercol
  FROM table2 t2 INNER JOIN cteUsers cte on t2.user_id = cte.user_id
  UNION
  SELECT t3.user_id, 'MatchedTable3' as match, t3.othercol
  FROM table3 t3 INNER JOIN cteUsers cte on t3.user_id = cte.user_id
)
SELECT u.user_id, coalesce(match, 'Not Matched At All') as matched, t.othercol
FROM cteUsers u LEFT OUTER JOIN cteTables t ON u.user_id = t.user_id;
```

I've put a [SqlFiddle up here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a585b/3) which will hopefully clear things up?.

Comment: Thanks! This works great. One additional question...how can I add something so that I know which table the result was found in. I tried something like `t1.othercol as something`, but no matter which table the result is found in, the result always shows `something` as the column name

Comment: You can add in a string literal / constant with the individual table `selects` in the `UNIONs`, although you'll need to deal with the not matched at all case - I've added a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to always return a row